# What is wrong here? I get a java.lang.ClassCastException error but I can't see where I have gone wrong

Tags: java, arraylist, queue, classcastexception

This is the first time I have really used Lists and Queues so this might be a very simple mistake.  Is it because my queue is full of objects that can't be cast to integers?

```
           //populate array
        for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
            numberarray[i] = i; 
        }
        // populate list with numbers from array
        List numList = Arrays.asList(numberarray);
        Collections.shuffle(numList);

        Queue queue = new LinkedList();
        queue.addAll(numList);

        int num1 = (Integer) queue.poll();
        assignPictures(button01, num1);
```

Comment: What is the `ClassCastException` you're getting? Why aren't you using generics to ensure type safety?

Comment: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer...by generics do you mean List<int>?

Comment: I mean `List<Integer>`. Primitives cannot be used as type parameters

Comment: Thank you.. I was trying List<int> instead of List<Integer>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use Generics and ArrayList/ArrayDeque unless  it's really performance critical and you use a lot of atomic types like int. Then you should have a look at 
http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html

Answer (score 9):

My guess is that the issue is here:

```
Arrays.asList(numberarray);
```

If `numberarray` is an `int[]` rather than an `Integer[]`, then that call will actually return a `List` of `int[]`s containing that array as one element.

The `ClassCastException` happens later when you try to cast the `int[]` object to an `Integer`.

Since Java doesn't support primitive collections there is no easy way to use `Arrays.asList` to wrap a primitive array - autoboxing doesn't work *en masse* like that. It's best to start off using an `Integer[]` if you plan to use it to back a `Collection`.

Part of the confusion comes from the fact that the method [`asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) takes [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). If it just took a `T[]` as an argument instead, the compiler wouldn't let you pass in an `int[]` since primitive arrays don't extend `Object[]`. But with varargs support, the compiler infers `T` as `int[]` and thinks you mean to build a `List` backed by a single-element `int[][]`.

As others have noted, the use of [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/generics.html) will really help you out with ambiguities like this and it's always a good idea to program using them:

```
List<Integer> numList = Arrays.asList(numberarray);
```

This line gives the following compile error, instead of allowing your code to fail at runtime:

> `incompatible types`
>   `required: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>`
>   `found:    java.util.List<int[]>`

**Side note:** Assuming you move to using an `Integer[]` don't forget that this means elements can now be `null`. Should this be the case a `NullPointerException` will be thrown when you unbox back to `int` - just be careful to ensure your implementation doesn't allow `null` elements or else check for `null` before unboxing.

Comment: you were right.. I ran it again and got ..  int[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: Thanks for the side note. I think after testing on my android device a few times and looking through my code my implementation doesn't allow for using the null element at the end of the queue. Thanks this post really helped me!