# Arrays.asList size() returns 1

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
int length = 10;
int[] theArray = new int[length];

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
   theArray[i] = (int) (Math.random()*10)+3;
}
System.out.println("generated array = " + Arrays.toString(theArray));
System.out.println("theArray.length = " + theArray.length);
System.out.println("list size = " + (Arrays.asList(theArray)).size());
```

it prints:

```
generated array = [6, 6, 10, 7, 3, 9, 10, 7, 4, 4]
theArray.length = 10
list size = 1
```

As per document Arrays.asList(theArray) returns fixed-size list backed by the specified arrayize. 
But why do I get the list size 1 here? why size is not reflected when using list. 
need help to find out gap and more insight about this.

I also checked my code couple of time incase of any silly gap and also google my observation but didnt see much insight of this.

Thanks,

Comment: You're adding the array to the list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248793/2591612

Comment: you have only one object in the ArrayList, and that is the array

Comment: Also related: [What is wrong here? I get a java.lang.ClassCastException error but I can't see where I have gone wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676185/what-is-wrong-here-i-get-a-java-lang-classcastexception-error-but-i-cant-see-w)

Comment: you should use Integer[] theArray = new Integer[length] instead. You see, this method signature is public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) and you cannot use primitives as T. So your int[] was "promoted" to an Object and added as a single Object into your List.

Comment: To be more clear on my above comment, if you try to add your array to a list, the syntax is `List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(theArray);` . It shows you are adding an `int[]` to the list, that means only one object. and Hence the size is 1.

Comment: There is no auto boxing from `int[]` to `Integer[]`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you put in one object (an array) in Arrays.asList(..).